# Unable to delete template

Tags: templates, c1-cms

I was trying to delete a template from the backend, but I always get this error message:

> The type is referenced by another type that does not allow cascade deletes. This operation is halted

This message appears for any template I try to delete.

How can I find out what is blocking the deletion?

The templates are MasterPage templates by the way, in case this is of any relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have one or more pages referencing the template you try to delete. You first need to either delete those pages or edit them and make them use another template (and publish that).

Comment: I think my error was forgetting to publish. Anywho, it worked now, thank you.